# "Add comment" appearing for my own deleted answers

Tags: discussion, bug, comments

A few moments ago I deleted one of my own answers here: [clang empty base class optimization (EBCO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17842720/241536)

I am logged in to the site, and am a 10K+ user, yet within my deleted answer I see:

> add comment (requires 50 reputation)

Clicking this does nothing.

I do not recall the ability to add a comment to a *deleted* answer.

Is this a bug?

Comment: This also seems to happen for all locked posts as well.